# want to change Maximum Upload Size of owncloud on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, webserver, owncloud-server

Installed Owncloud on Ubuntu 14.04
i want to change the default Maximum Upload Size that is 513 MB to 3 gb .
Please suggest me .
Thanks

Comment: Check your php settings for upload.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the latest Owncloud log in, click your username at the top right and then press 'Admin'. If you scroll down you will see 'File handling' and you can change the max upload size there.

If this box is grayed out, ssh into your web server (or open a terminal to whatever system is running the web server) and type:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/owncloud
```

Afterwards repeat the steps above and find 'File Handling', you should now be able to change the max upload size.

Comment: It is not necessary to give write access to the entire owncloud folder.